# How to fix VScode gutter indicator artifacts when the text editor is changed?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my active function:

```js
  const updateTrigger = () => {
    if (vscode.window.activeTextEditor) {
      updateDecorations(context);
      pickupOutJumpPoints(context);
    }
  };
  vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor(
    updateTrigger,
    null,
    context.subscriptions
  );
```

updateDecorations:

```js
const PINLINEDECORATION = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
  gutterIconPath: PUSHPINPATH,
  gutterIconSize: "contain",
  rangeBehavior: vscode.DecorationRangeBehavior.ClosedClosed,
});

function updateDecorations(ctx: vscode.ExtensionContext): void {
  const jps = getJumpPoints(ctx);
  const editor = getEditor();
  if (jps === undefined) {
    return;
  } else {
    editor.setDecorations(
      PINLINEDECORATION,
      jps.map(function (point: JumpPoint): vscode.DecorationOptions {
        return {
          range: new vscode.Range(point.to.position, point.to.position),
          hoverMessage: "$(alert)",
        };
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Because i need my decorations to remain pinned into a single line, I'm having to reset decorations after every text editor change, this creates icon artifacts, is there a better way to achieve the same pinned effect?

Artifact demonstration:
https://i.gyazo.com/383d8e5979e72131e3b61a33ca8769ae.mp4

Answer (score 1):

By default decorations follow the line, so if you want "Fixed to line 8" even if "Content of line 8 moves to line 9" (honestly I haven't seen a use case), then what you have will do

Comment: Ah okay, I just realized, this would be better off if it moved along with the contents. Anyways, I'm going to leave this open for an answer in fixing the artifacts if anyone in the future needs it.